# Railsで has_many の要素の削除を遅延する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

の関係のとき

```rb
foo1 = Foo.new
foo1.bar.build
```

とすれば、保存を遅延させることができます
create を使えば直ちに保存されます

しかし削除では直ちに削除する方法はあっても、削除を遅延させる方法がないように思います

```rb
foo1 = Foo.find(1)
# どれも DELETE が発行される
foo1.bar.clear
foo1.bar = []
foo1.bar.replace([Bar.new])
```

Rails には build に対応するような、削除の遅延処理を行う機構は用意されていないのでしょうか？

Comment: こちら、なぜ削除を遅延させたいのかは背景がありますでしょうか？　もし [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)になっていれば回答ができるかもな、と考えています。たとえば一時的に特定の ActiveRecord を無視したいのであれば where すれば済む、などです。

Comment: データの「増」「減」が別々に扱われているのはRailsの汎化設計の失敗ではないか、という単純な疑問が発端です 実用上は、データの「変換層」「永続化層（副作用）」を分離することができれば不具合の出現抑制や、トランザクションの範囲狭小化が期待できるが、Rails はそれをするための方法を用意しないので、手続き的な記述が強要されている？という点で困っています